# mysql query combine 2 selects on one table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I combine 2 selects on one table like this?

Table T1:

```
id | status | ts
1  | 0      |2019-02-22 00:00:00
2  | 0      |2019-02-22 00:00:00
3  | 0      |2019-02-22 00:00:00
1  | 1      |2019-02-22 01:00:00
3  | 1      |2019-02-22 01:30:00
1  | 0      |2019-02-22 02:00:00
3  | 0      |2019-02-22 03:00:00
```

I want to find last values of `status = 0` and `status = 1` for each ID

```
1  | 0      |2019-02-22 02:00:00 with 1       | 1      |2019-02-22 01:00:00
2  | 0      |2019-02-22 00:00:00
3  | 0      |2019-02-22 03:00:00 with 3       | 1      |2019-02-22 01:30:00
```

I tried:

```
SELECT id, status, MAX(ts) 
 from T1 
where status = 1 Union SELECT id, status, MAX(ts) from T1 where status = 0
```

but not ok... :o(

And maybe calculate time difference between 2 states of change for each ID...

Comment: Which MySQL version do you have? `SELECT VERSION()` and can you also post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE T1` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should to the trick :

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN ts END) ts_0, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN ts END) ts_1 
FROM T1
GROUP BY id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oSjWZ4PtDZHvwSHWLhL2W6/0)** :

```
| id  | ts_0                | ts_1                |
| --- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2019-02-22 02:00:00 | 2019-02-22 01:00:00 |
| 2   | 2019-02-22 00:00:00 |                     |
| 3   | 2019-02-22 03:00:00 | 2019-02-22 01:30:00 |
```

Comment: Since you're taking the `MAX`, it doesn't really matter whether timestamps are increasing or not.

Comment: @Nick : that's correct ; I removed that mention from my answer, thanks for the notice !

Comment: Welcome @SlavoS ! Consider accepting my answer if it properly solved your problem.